AWS SageMaker Jupyter instance connection to RDS proxy failing
**> Is there a way to get my sagemaker or multiple sagemakers to access

the RDS Proxy with an existing postgre database.
Basically, I launched a jupyter notebook instance from sagemaker and
tried these python codes but they failed.Since its a proxy
authentication, my token works but I'm getting a error saying
Connection to server , port 5432 faild, password authentication failed
for username. Any recommendations on how to connect sagemaker to an
RDS proxy postgre database, please.
==================**

{
import boto3
import psycopg2

###### AWS RDS details
region = '       '  # Sydney region perhaps
db_username = 'your_db_username'
db_endpoint = 'your-rds-proxy-endpoint.amazonaws.com'
db_name = 'your_db_name'

###### Boto3 RDS client
rds_client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)

###### Generate IAM authentication token
token = rds_client.generate_db_auth_token(
    DBHostname=db_endpoint,
    Port=5432,
    DBUsername=db_username
)

###### Connect to the database
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host=db_endpoint,
    port=5432,
    user=db_username,
    password=token,
    dbname=db_name,

sslmode='require'
)

print("Connection established")
}

